# in Homomorphic Encryption Standard, why in the LWE increasing security level yields smaller ciphertext?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, lwe

I am currently reading  [Homomorphic Encryption Standard](https://projects.csail.mit.edu/HEWorkshop/HomomorphicEncryptionStandard2018.pdf). 
May I ask that for table 1 in the link, why increasing the security level will yield a smaller ciphertext size (log q)?

I attach a screenshot below
[image]
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple terms, since smaller q (i.e. bit size) gives higher security level, and ciphertext is presented in modolus q form, therefore when keeping other parameters the same, smaller q gives smaller ciphertext and higher security level at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So by increasing the log q to tolerate more homomorphic operations, does it means that this indeed decrease the security level?

Comment: @jswang to some extent yes